# Should feature modules have it's own Interceptor and Http service?

Tags: angular

Is it advisable to have services for http calls to api and interceptors for those http in a feature modules? Or should these services be kept somewhere like in core modules?

My understanding is if we keep services related to a feature in it's module then it helps in keeping in more related services and components together. However I have often come across of using a core module which should have all the interceptors and service related to http.

What will be a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should try to always keep your services as close to the module(s) were they are used as possible.

When you only use a service in one feature module place it within this module.
When you reuse a service in multiple feature modules place it in a "shared" folder. However try to stay as close to your feature modules as possible.

Interceptors are global for your application, keep those in a "shared" or "core" location in your project.

For reference: [Angular Styleguide Shared feature module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-10)

For reference: [Angular Styleguide Core feature module](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-11)